# Regular Expression to trim number at the end of a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a file which consists of string. The file also contains date.
I want to remove number at the end of the string.
For example-

```
Str = 'part-at-1234'
```

New string should be `str= 'part-at'`

I have written the following regex

```
(-\d+)
```

My regex also matches the date.
I want to write a regular expression that only matches the string not include date.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the format of the date?

Comment: The date format is Dd-mm-yy

Answer (score 1):

try this, `\d+` any digit one or more & `$` matches the end of the string

```
import re

re.sub("-\d+$",'' , "part-at-1234")

'part-at'
```

Answer (score 1):

If there date has a format of for example 12-12-20, you could match the hyphen and  1+ digits and assert not a digit before the hyphen.

```
(?<!\d)-\d+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OwDjEV/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/O9tz2p)

Example code

```
import re

regex = r"(?<!\d)-\d+$"
test_str = ("part-at-1234\n"
    "part-at-12-12-2020")

result = re.sub(regex, "", test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
part-at
part-at-12-12-20
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expressions:

> `.+\D+(?=\d+)`

Or you could always select the numbers at the end with this, and then replace it with and empty string:

> `\d+$`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
s = re.sub("^\d+\s|\s\d+\s|\s\d+$", " ", p)
```